# Moisture spot on deck

Tags: finishing

We built a deck last summer and now we are ready to stain. The only issue is we left a rug on it all year and now we have a rectangle that is a different color because it held moisture. Should we stain and it eventually fade or should we wait. Will it eventually fade with a stain? Please advise

Comment: You should wait at least a few days to a week if possible, but I suspect that the mark won't go away entirely. You should definitely not stain now. After waiting, if the colour is still uneven you'll have to do something to fix that before staining but the good news is that power washing may be enough, see [previous Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3778/can-i-run-pressure-treated-deck-boards-through-thickness-planer/3787#3787).

Answer (score 1):

If you have scraps of the decking, try to reproduce the problem.  If you can do that, you have a way to test solutions.

My guess is that it's some form of oxidation.  A reducing bleach may be sufficient.  Things to try:

- Conventional chlorine bleach.
- Oxygen bleach
- oxalic acid (radiator cleaner)
- wood bleach (sold in outdoor living departments at outrageous prices.)

Not all things that remove the stain are permanent -- might come back.

Once you can remove the stain on the test wood, put a finish on it and put it out in the weather again.

---

Another solution:

Put chunks of similar sized carpet in random places on the deck, and do the same reaction there.  NOW the problem looks like it was planned, and you will pick up lots of karma from the craft crowd.